# Why can't I pass LeetCode exercise 139?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am looking at this [leetcode challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/):

> Given a non-empty string *s* and a dictionary *wordDict* containing a list of non-empty words, determine if *s* can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

```js
var wordBreak = function(s, wordDict) {
  const memo = new Map();
  const wordSet = new Set(wordDict);

  function toMemo(s) {
    if (memo.has(s)) return memo.get(s);
    if (wordSet.has(s)) {
      memo.set(s, true);
      return true
    }

    for (let i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
      let leftStr = s.substr(0, i);
      let rightStr = s.substr(i);
      if (toMemo(leftStr) && wordSet.has(rightStr)) {
        memo.set(s, true)
        return true;
      }
    }
    memo.set(s, true)
    return false;
  }
  return toMemo(s);
};
```

My code does not pass the following test case:

Your input：

```
"aaaaaaa"
["aaaa","aa"]
```

Output：`true`
Expected：`false`

How can I deal with this problem? I don't understand why this example worked and mine didn't?

Comment: I got `true` as a result for `wordBreak("aaaaaaa", ["aaaa", "aa"])`, so I am not sure what I am missing... Is that your function above, or the websites? Are you expecting `false`? Looks like your Japanese labels for input/output/expected denote that... I assume it's because the input length is neither divisible by 4 nor 2 since the length is 7. I assume it works for `['aaaa', 'aaa']`?

Comment: This suggested solution seems to be where you are heading: _[JavaScript Brute Force/ recursive approach and Brute Force/ recursive  with memoization approach](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/discuss/822428/JavaScript-Brute-Force-recursive-approach-and-Brute-Force-recursive-with-memoization-approach)_

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (toMemo(leftStr) && toMemo(rightStr)) ?

Comment: Also the memo.set(s, true) right before you return false should be memo.set(s, false) or not?

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake in your code is where you return `false`. In that case you should not do:

```
memo.set(s, true)
return false;
```

But:

```
memo.set(s, false);
return false;
```